# Error in dynamic statement PL/PGSQL (functions and operators can take at most one set argument)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to execute the code below. I need this because, i wanted to pass the table names as parameters (`character varying`):

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '||tmp_table||' AS SELECT study,
'||unnest(columns)||' AS variable_id, '||unnest_table(tblName)||
' AS variable_value FROM '||tblName;
```

However, I run into the error below:

**functions and operators can take at most one set argument**

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is the code for the unnest_table function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_table(_tbl text)
RETURNS SETOF text LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $func$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
     SELECT unnest(ARRAY[' || (
SELECT string_agg(a.attname || '::text', ',' ORDER  BY a.attnum)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a 
WHERE  a.attrelid = _tbl::regclass
AND    a.attnum > 0
AND    a.attisdropped = false
) || '])
FROM   ' || _tbl::regclass;

END
$func$;
```

Comment: `unnest_table` is not a normal built-in function. How is it defined? Are you trying to do something like a `string_agg` ?

Comment: I edited the question to include the definition of the unnest_table function.

Comment: That's an incredibly bizarre way to write such a function. You create an array literal using `string_agg` then `unnest` it? *boggle* ?

Comment: It's an important step of unpivoting. The problem isn't there though since I already tested that although with hard-coded table names.

Comment: Your code is *a complete mess*. Please start by describing what you want to achieve, add an example and what the result should be. To top it off, provide your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `unnest` & your `unnest_table` both returns `SETOF <sometype>`, and `operators can take at most one set argument`, so f.ex.:

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']);

-- will return

unnest
------
"a"
"b"
"c"


SELECT unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']) || 'd';

-- will return

?column?
--------
"ad"
"bd"
"cd"


SELECT unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']) || 'd' || unnest(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']);

-- will return

ERROR: functions and operators can take at most one set argument
SQL state: 0A000
```

**Edit**: but i highly doubt, you want to create that much table with the same name - also `EXECUTE` does not accept more than one row:

```
ERROR: query "..." returned more than one row
SQL state: 21000
```

I think you should use something like the [`array_to_string()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html) function.