# How to calculate numbers nested in Postgresql JSON?

Tags: json, postgresql

I would like to do some operations with numbers stored in Postgresql 9.4 `JSON` format. Suppose I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id SERIAL, a JSON);

INSERT INTO t (a)
VALUES ('[[0.1, 2.0], [0.3, 4.0], [0.5, 6.0]]'),
       ('[[0.7, 8.0], [0.9, 10.0]]');
```

So I can decompose that with e.g. `json_array_elements()`:

```
SELECT id, json_array_elements(a) AS sub1 FROM t;

id |   sub1
----------------
 1 | [0.1, 2.0]
 1 | [0.3, 4.0]
 1 | [0.5, 6.0]
 2 | [0.7, 8.0]
 2 | [0.9, 10.0]
```

Note, that the number of elements may vary. Now I would like to do some calculations with the sub-elements, like:

```
SELECT id,
       ((json_array_elements(a)->>0)::FLOAT) *
       ((json_array_elements(a)->>1)::FLOAT) as result
FROM t
```

However I get the error: `ERROR: functions and operators can take at most one set argument`. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an (implicit) [`LATERAL` join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) instead:

```
SELECT id, (e->>0)::float * (e->>1)::float as result
FROM   t, json_array_elements(a) e
```

Set-returning functions in the `SELECT` works very special in PostgreSQL:

- [Why does PostgreSQL combine series in a wrong way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202501/why-does-postgresql-combine-series-in-a-wrong-way)
- [Why do these join differently based on size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214657/why-do-these-join-differently-based-on-size)

The exact reason of your error is that, you tried to multiply two sets (which is not allowed). PostgreSQL can calculate `<element> * <element>` (will be single value), `<set> * <element>` (or vice versa; will be set-valued), but not `<set> * <set>`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `json_array_elements()` returns **setof** json.

You should better access elements by path, like this:

```
SELECT
        id,
        (a#>>'{0,0}')::float * (a#>>'{0,1}')::float as result
    FROM processing.t;
```

And about error is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903492/error-in-dynamic-statement-pl-pgsql-functions-and-operators-can-take-at-most-on).

If this is not an option, you can use a subquery:

```
select
        id,
        (a->>0)::float * (a->>1)::float as result
    from (
        SELECT
                id,
                json_array_elements(a) as a
            FROM processing.t
    ) t;
```

In this case you are able to write expressions the way you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice answer. But actually I do not know how many items will be nested within the first element. So I'd need a more flexible solution. I will try to update my question.

Answer (score 0):

*If version of PostgreSQL is equal or more than 10 this code from current question, do not cause error.* I made fiddle with [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dgrnjLoiKBsyGZurYU79Lg/0).

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (id SERIAL, a JSON);

INSERT INTO t (a)
VALUES ('[[0.1, 2.0], [0.3, 4.0], [0.5, 6.0]]'),
       ('[[0.7, 8.0], [0.9, 10.0]]');

SELECT id,
       ((json_array_elements(a)->>0)::FLOAT) *
       ((json_array_elements(a)->>1)::FLOAT) as result
FROM t;
```